# Simulating the step response of a closed-loop system with disturbance

Tags: control, control-system, feedback, pid-controller, matlab

How do I simulate in MatLab the step response of a closed-loop system with disturbance (see image below)? I can't seem to derive a straightforward transfer function output/input due to the disturbance.

[image: closed loop system with disturbance]

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve this? Homework questions need to show some attempt at a solution so that anyone attempting an answer can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: I tried using the equation output = GR/1+G + D/1+G where R and D are the input and disturbance respectively. I have derived a transfer function, but the computations become cumbersome.